# New SQL Monitor Showing Database Deadlocks, Should I be alarmed?

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server, lock

We recently installed a SQL Monitoring tool that is raising High Alerts for SQL Server Deadlocks on my SDE database at random times during the day.

Using the information provided in the Alert I have found that the deadlock is relating back to  the SDE_state_locks Table.

SQL info: SQL Server 2008 R2 (x64)

ArcSDE 10.0

Comment: See http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/27034